# AttributeError __exit__ while trying to save a model.db from a form in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, forms, django-1.7

I have created a model with django.db.models.Model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And a form using django.forms.ModelForm.

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = []
```

Due tu previous problem overidding init when I should not have, I unit tested that MyModel.save() worked. So the unit test are passing. I also can populate the database with an init script, so i don't think there's a problem with my model. But I can't save it when usng the data from a form.

This is the code I use to recover my object from the form :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        my_model_object = form.save()
        return render(request, 'validate.html')
else:
    form = MyModelForm()
return render(request, 'create_mymodel.html',
              {'form': form})
```

Infortunately when I call save() I get the following error :

```
my_project/views/views.py in my_function
my_model_object = form.save()
...django/db/models/base.py in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
...django/db/models/base.py in save_base
 self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
...django/db/models/base.py in _save_parents
self._save_table(cls=parent, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
...django/db/models/base.py in _save_table
 result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
...django/db/models/base.py in _do_insert
 using=using, raw=raw)
...django/db/models/manager.py in   manager_method
  return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
...django/db/models/query.py in _insert
  return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
...django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
   with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:

AttributeError at my_url/
__exit__

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/my_url/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    __exit__
```

It work if I use save(commit=False), but of course my object is not in database. I also tried to use all the attributs in form and to instantiate and save a MyModel, but it does not work either. In fact, if I try to save it at any point I get the error. I based my code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Instead of the prosaic "I have a `AttributeError __exit__` coming all the way"... you should paste the traceback. That would be more helpful.

Comment: Sorry, very true, I added the stacktrace, I hope this help.

Comment: Though a very wild guess, the only thing i see slightly off is that the `exclude` attribute is an empty list. Try changing that to `fields = "__all__"`

Comment: I still have the error with fields = "__all__". It look better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had to put this in production even if it did not work, I did.. The problem disapeared. So I thougth  it was a problem of database configuration. Then the problem appeared identical on an unrelated django project where I happened to have copy-pasted the debug configuration.

It turned out that it was caused by the configuration of the django debug toolbar, I don't know exactly where, because I simply supressed it. Check your settings file if you have the same problem !